# Animate circle in Android with data

Tags: android

I am looking to achieve the following:

https://codepen.io/kyledws/pen/Gvelt/

In Android. But I'm not interested in the hover part. When you hover over the circle in this example, the circle decreases. However, I would like the circle to increase (animated) on the activity's onStart() method. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
/* (IGNORE THIS) */
```

I'd like to achieve this by updating the circle with data sent as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use one of these ......

[ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

[Circle-Progress-View](https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View)

[Progressbar](http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/09/android-custom-circle-progressbar.html)

[Progressbutton](https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c)

[One App At A time](http://mrigaen.blogspot.in/2013/12/create-circular-progress-bar-in-android.html)

enjoy coding....